# SCCM 2012 R2 - How to specify custom SCCM server IP / name using MDT in PE

Tags: sccm-2012, mdt-2012, mdt

I am attempting to automate OS installations using SCCM 2012 R2 (MDT). Clients are failing when the PE attempts to contact the SCCM server as the address is being specified as `server.example.com` instead of `server.subdomain.example.com`.

If I press F8 when PE gets the error I can see the SCCM server as `server.subdomain.example.com` so I know it's available via this path.

How do I set this value in the task sequence manually or on the fly in PE?

Comment: Have you tried setting _SMSTSMP and _SMSTSMPPort as variables in the task sequence? See this:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273375.aspx

Comment: Those look to be read-only.

Comment: Crap... I just did MDT training with an MS consultant and I know we covered this.  Let me ping him by email and see if he can give me a quick answer.  Stand by.

Comment: Can you do an ipconfig from PE and see if you have multiple DNS suffix search lists?

Comment: ipconfig /all shows only one entry for 'dns suffix search list'. The issue is that PE is looking for 'server.domain-name' instead of 'server.com'. The domain name isn't in DNS anywhere - it's just my machine. The server.com entry is available though which is why I'm hoping to update the PE settings to use it instead.

Comment: So are you saying you have domain.local as your internal domain and domain.com as your external domain/website?

Comment: In SCCM the server is identifying itself as 'server.domain.etc'. What I need is for PE to search for 'server.subdomain.subdomain.edu'. IE Look for it in a different place from the default.

Comment: This is what my MS guy sent me (his is in quotes)... "When PE is created it will look to see how the MP is publishing to AD.  I don’t know of a way to change this in PE on the fly.  I guess you could test his theory by entering the IP as static and giving PE the DNS Suffix.  I realize that his is running DHCP but if he boots, F8, ipconfig /all, record the IP information then chooses to set a static IP and places the IP, Subnet, GW and the DNS Suffix he wants, this would test what he is saying.  I not sure that it is a FQDN issue without looking at the logs.  Best I can come up with…"

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. Thanks though. I'm going to rebuild the server / site and see if I can fix the addressing that way.

Comment: Sounds good... sorry we couldn't get you down the right path.  Probably for the sake of your question though we should answer it that it can't be manually done pre PE and the way I suggested is one workaround.  I can post it or you can, let me know.

Comment: Ate you talking about attempting to contact the server after the task sequence has *started*?? Or, are you not able to find task sequences? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to change this setting in the task sequence or on the fly in PE.  When PE is created it will look to see how the MP/SCCM server is publishing its name to AD.

What you could do is enter a static IP and give PE the DNS Suffix. Even if you're running DHCP you can boot to PE, hit F8, do an ipconfig /all, record the IP information then choose to set a static IP and place the IP, Subnet, gateway and DNS Suffix on this same range allowing you to try to hit a custom DP/SCCM server.  Again though, it will depend on how SCCM is publishing to AD.

The short answer is no, but as always there is an alternative.